# Arrows inside table

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to LateX. I need to get the following table along with the arrows. The table is quite easy to do but, it has turned impossible to draw the blue and black arrows. If you could give me a hand?

This is my code so far:

```
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
\sffamily
&      A    &   B  \\ \hline
1 & $r_{1A} $& $r_{1B} $ \\ \hline
2 & $r_{2A}$  & $r_{BA} $ \\ \hline  

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tikzmark` this is rather straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
\sffamily
&      A    &   B  \\ \hline
1 & $\tikzmarknode{a11}{r_{1A}}$~ & ~$\tikzmarknode{a12}{r_{1B}}$ \\ \hline
2 & $\tikzmarknode{a21}{r_{2A}}$~  & ~$\tikzmarknode{a22}{r_{BA}}$ \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[stealth-stealth,blue] (a11.north east) -- (a12.north west)
node[midway,above,scale=0.4,black] (dAB) {$d_{AB}$};
\draw[-stealth,blue] (a21.south east) -- (a22.south west);
\draw[-stealth,blue] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] (dAB.south|-a22);
\draw[stealth-stealth] (a11.east) -- (a21.east)
node[pos=0.5,above right,scale=0.4,black] (d12) {$d_{12}$};
\draw[-stealth] (d12.north) to[out=0,in=180] ([yshift=-1ex]a12.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is a version in which `\sffamily` has an effect and the stuff is more readable via `contour`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\bgroup\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{rc}
& Movies \\
Users &
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
&      A    &   B  \\ \hline
1 & $\tikzmarknode{a11}{r_{1A}}$~ & ~$\tikzmarknode{a12}{r_{1B}}$ \\ \hline
2 & $\tikzmarknode{a21}{r_{2A}}$~  & ~$\tikzmarknode{a22}{r_{BA}}$ \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}  
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[stealth-stealth,blue] (a11.north east) -- (a12.north west)
node[midway,above,scale=0.4,black] (dAB) {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
\draw[-stealth,blue] (a21.south east) -- (a22.south west);
\draw[-stealth,blue] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] (dAB.south|-a22);
\draw[stealth-stealth] (a11.east) -- (a21.east)
node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.4,black] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
\draw[-stealth] (d12.north) to[out=0,in=180] ([yshift=-1ex]a12.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that you could also use a `tikz` matrix, but then right alignment and drawing the cell borders requires slightly more work.

Comment: Thank you very much! How about the ones in the middle? Those are much tougher to draw, right?

Comment: @naveganteX Not really. I added them.

Comment: True genius! I really appreciate it! To me, it is actually quite hard. I’ll improve my skills over time!

Comment: @naveganteX I am sure you will. Even ducks and marmot can use Ti*k*Z. ;-)

Comment: Last version is outstanding! Thank you so much. I tried to end the complete table by adding Movies and Users labels. I will share it. I did it by nesting tables.

Answer (score 0):

@marmot Nested version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
& Movies\\
Users&  
\begin{tabular}{ l | c | r }
\sffamily
&      A    &   B  \\ \hline
1 & $\tikzmarknode{a11}{r_{1A}}$~ & ~$\tikzmarknode{a12}{r_{1B}}$ \\ \hline
2 & $\tikzmarknode{a21}{r_{2A}}$~  & ~$\tikzmarknode{a22}{r_{BA}}$ \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[stealth-stealth,blue] (a11.north east) -- (a12.north west)
node[midway,above,scale=0.4,black] (dAB) {$d_{AB}$};
\draw[-stealth,blue] (a21.south east) -- (a22.south west);
\draw[-stealth,blue] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] (dAB.south|-a22);
\draw[stealth-stealth] (a11.east) -- (a21.east)
node[pos=0.5,above right,scale=0.4,black] (d12) {$d_{12}$};
\draw[-stealth] (d12.north) to[out=0,in=180] ([yshift=-1ex]a12.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```